# Moving a Visual Studio project from a different computer?

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2019, and I am trying to open a project sent by my friend. However, when I tried opening the solution or the project, this error shows up:

```
An error occurred in '[Unknown]' while attempting to open <filename>

File path: (The path from my friend's computer)
Frame GUID: 
Frame mode:
Error code: 0x80004005
```

I have tried to change the file path, but the file path is correct in my computer, so what is this file path referencing to ?

Comment: please add more details . Are you trying to open it using remote  or you have copied that project in your computer

Comment: Yes, this is on my computer

Comment: are you both on same vs code version

Comment: It should be, I think the project is still using the file path from his computer, this is the first time I have ever seen this happened.

Comment: then it's not visual studio issue you need to update your project settings .

Comment: Okay, can you tell me how ?

Comment: visual studio don't stores your path to project , it's the project files  , look at your project .json for VS Code used for build and run and if you are using build management tools then look into them what paths are you providing

Answer (score 5):

Close the solution, then delete the folder named `.vs` (note the dot) in the project directory and restart Visual Studio. This folder contains cached data that's computer-dependent.

You can also just close the window with the error and reopen the file from the solution explorer.

Comment: It doesn't work, it is still the same after I open it up

Comment: When exactly do you see the error? When you try to open a source file?

Comment: Whenever I tried to open using the solution file, but actually I think your solution worked but instead of the solution file, I have to open each individual source file and header file.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I renamed projects in the solution file (using notepad++). When I opened the solution in Visual Studio I had the old files opened in my dev environment from last time I had the solution open. I just closed those and opened the files from solution explorer.